# Qt pattern recognition of segments of a string

Tags: c++, qt

does Qt have the ability to recognize that for instance you are writing a list of mails and after each mail to turn it into a widget with an **x** button (sort of like Gmail does). Is there some built-in functionality for this or must it be made from the ground up?

Comment: It needs to be made from the ground up. And this is a good question.

Comment: I think you have to make it from scratch. and i'm interested in this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think It's easier to use LineEdit and listen to it's onchange signal. In on change slot search for email inside LineEdit text using RegExp. If you find an appropriate email (maybe surrounded with spaces) then add a Label with the delete icon in front of LineEdit and remove added email from LineEdit text. That's all!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a look on the QtGraphics sub-module of QtGui especially on [QGraphicsTextItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicstextitem.html) and QGraphicsScene.

You will just have to manage the layout (or use an existing one), the items' look & feel and the [delete buttons](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicssceneevent.html).

Even if it is nearly from scratch, you will not have to code the rendering.